# How to play a Tank Destroyer in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've played several *Tank Destroyers*, *SPGs* and *Light Tanks* so far and reached **Tier V** with each of them. (**Panzer IV**, **M41**, **StuG III**)

My observation is that the overall difficulty level increases because you are faced with tanks which are more tough nuts to crack. In case of an **SPG** I had to learn how to properly aim at the weak spots and/or calculate with tank speed (I noticed that the higher the tier of the tank the opponent sits in the more aware they get of a possible SPG threat). I also get bigger guns (*155mm howitzer in **M41** for example*)

In my Light/Medium tanks I had to learn how to use cover so I don't die instantly and how I can use my speed to work myself around bigger threats. I do feel that the higher tier I get my tanks become more capable.

In case of my tank destroyer **StuG III** I feel that this is not the case. I'm not as fast as a lighter tank, and I do not have the firepower of a heavy tank. (I can't shoot behind covers either). The StuG III has the same derp gun as the *Hetzer* but since it is a higher tier I often face *Tigers* and *KV-1s*. I also noticed that since the StuG III's armor is not as sloped as the Hetzer's I am more vulnerable. I don't feel the same progression with tiers as I do with other tank types. **It seems to me that I did not learn something important about playing tank destroyers since the higher tier I get the less fun I have with them.**

Do you have some guidelines for a puzzled tank destroyer player?
*StuG III specific answers are also welcome*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many tank destroyers, and particularly the Stug III have a great camo rating, which means that if you play carefully the enemy team will have great difficulty spotting you.

While playing this particular tank, and other TDs like it, try to stay behind the rest of your team and lay down supporting fire form a sniping position.

If you're not familiar with how camo and spotting works, I recommend [this camouflage tutorial.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5NlTeCSjJU)

Some general tips:

- Stay behind a bush, but remember that firing your gun will temporarily remove the additional camo value of the bush
- Equipping your TD with a camo net, and training the crew in camouflage will greatly increase your overall camo rating.
- Remember that moving your tank, even by slightly turning it lowers your camo value. With TDs and SPGs you can prevent accidentally turning your tank by locking it in place by using the (default) X key.
- The commander's sixth sense skill is great on TDs as it will help you know when you're spotted.
- The Stug III is responsible fast and mobile, if you are spotted or think you might be soon, relocate to a new position from which you can safely snipe.

Comment: Should I stay **behind** or **in** the brush? I thought that I should stay *in* it. I already have a camo net and camo painting on it. Now this might seem really dumb but what is the sixth sense skill? If I click the personal profile it says **"Perk comes into effect after it reaches 100%"** What does that mean? My commander needs to be 100% to have this skill or I can train him somehow?

Comment: Stay behind the bush, better yet, put as many bushes and trees as possible between you and the enemy. As long as friendly tank is spotting them you will be able to see them (but they won't see you). To get sixth sense, first train your commander up to 100%. Then select the sixth sense, and train that up to a 100%. (this will take quite a long time, but remember you can take crews with you from one tank to the next). Once you have it, a light bub icon will appear on your screen once spotted as seen here: http://i49.tinypic.com/oup9bt.png

Comment: The second part of this movie explains the concept pretty well, I highly recommend watching it: http://youtu.be/HX0znHSeDMU?t=3m18s

Comment: Excellent video! Thank you guys! I was not aware of the skill training for crew members nor the option to carry over guys from previous tiers!

Comment: Additional tips: Stay behind bush so that bush is semi translucent to spot enemies, then when you do spot them, move back alittle so that the bush becomes opaque, then take your shot. This way your are completely undetectable, since a semi translucent bush does not hide gun flashes (which make you detectable more easily), but opaque ones do (it's a distance of 15m from the bush I believe)

Comment: @Populus "translucent bush does not hide gun flashes but opaque ones do". I've been playing WOT for ages and I did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As an alternate answer to the excellent camo-oriented answer @Xenox provided, there are also tank destroyers that do not rely on camo:

- British TD starting from the AT range
- German TD starting from Jagdpanther 2/Ferdinand
- US TD starting from T28/T28 Prot

Generally there are 3 types of tank destroyers:

- Camo-oriented: They are usually low profile, and turret-less
- Maneuverable: Either with turret, or very good turning speed
- Heavy armoured: slow, above average frontal armour

The camo one, @Xenox has answered.

For maneauvrable TDs (e.g. E-25, German turreted TD line...etc.) It's all about positioning, dishing out as much damage as you can, then withdraw and re-position, rinse and repeat. So learning how, and when to flank, learning paths to take so you can quickly retreat and move somewhere else, is the most important aspect for these kind of TDs.

Heavy armoured TDs (JP-E100, T110E4, T95...etc) is about finding the spots that conceal your weakpoints, avoiding being flanked, whether by positioning, or knowing where your team mates are and how they can protect your flanks. Knowing when to push forward is also very important due to the slow movement speeds of these tanks, not being at the scene of an important skirmish can determine a match's outcome. As a heavily armoured TD you can also take the role of drawing attention, since your shots hurt *alot* people tend to want to take down TDs as quick as possible, so if you can utilise your armour well, you can, for example, draw attention away from your flanking team mates.

There are numerous ways to play a TD, so it's not restricted to what I said above, e.g. a heavy TD can also play camo-oriented, if they can find bushes that are big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of weak spots, stay back/hidden, hide part of your tank behind an obstacle if you can, and use the gun with the highest penetration if possible.

My typical equipment loadout for a TD is: Vents, Camo, Binoculars. I'll sometimes swap out vents for a rammer.

Comment: That's common sense which is written on the wot website. :)

Answer (score 0):

For mobility based TDs like the hellcat or the achilles, use you team to take damage and play back. From there you can do a lot of damage and not take a lot or any. For tanks like the hetzer and archer and stug III (camo tanks), do kinda the same thing except more camping and less following the team. TDs are the hardest and one of the most important, since they can deal with heavys nicely! Heavies are OP at tier five and there's nothing you can do!